# Sum values of items in the ListView

Tags: android, listview, integer

I have a ListView with SimpleCursorAdapter showing integers. How I can add all these integers and display the total in a String?

[see this screenshot to see my idea](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2tjx9v85WTOVWlORDBRZ3hCdlk/view?usp=sharing)

Look well Toast showing the values of each item, but the TextView (total) does not

```
public static final String ROW_ID = "row_id";
private static final String TITLE_APROVADAS = "title";
private static final String CREDITOS_APROVADAS = "creditos";
private ListView noteListView;
private SimpleCursorAdapter noteAdapter;
private Cursor cursor;
private TextView total;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_principal);

    noteListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewTarea);
    total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.texto_contador); 

    noteAdapter  = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.aprovadas_textview,cursor,
    new String[] {TITLE_APROVADAS,CREDITOS_APROVADAS},

    new int[] {R.id.titulo_aprovadas_texto_listview, R.id.creditos_aprovadas_texto_listview},1){

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    view.findViewById(R.id.titulo_aprovadas_texto_listview);
    TextView credito = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.creditos_aprovadas_texto_listview);

    String txtCredito=credito.getText().toString();
    int losCreditos=Integer.parseInt(txtCredito);
    total.setText(""+losCreditos);
    Toast.makeText(ZMainActivity.this, ""+losCreditos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     return view;
   }
   };
    noteListView.setAdapter(noteAdapter);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new GetNotes().execute((Object[]) null);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    Cursor cursor = noteAdapter.getCursor();
    if(cursor != null ){
    cursor.deactivate();
    noteAdapter.changeCursor(null);
    super.onStop();}
}

public class GetNotes extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Cursor> {
    Aprovadas_DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new Aprovadas_DatabaseConnector(ZMainActivity.this);
    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // Open the database
        dbConnector.open();
        return (dbConnector.ListAllNotes());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        noteAdapter.changeCursor(result);
        // Close Database
        dbConnector.close();

    }}
```

}

Comment: No rights to your screenshot, Use the data you send in your simple cursor adapter.

Comment: if you paste code for your adapter and listview here, i could provide you sample

Comment: and btw, the only reason you get so many down votes it's because you provided no code for your adapter or listview

Comment: Thanks I edited the question. I hope to help me with my problem

Answer (score 0):

You should sum up all values from the data provider (guessing an ArrayList). Iterate over the array and add the current value to sum and then display it.

You would need to do something like this

```
List<Nodes> listOfNodes = dbConnector.ListAllNotes();
int sum = 0;
int size = listOfNodes.size();
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
   sum += listOfNodes.get(i).getCreditos();
}
```

You may need to create the method getCreditos to return a value of credits in each node, but appart from that this is the basic idea.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the problem is that I am a newbie and would like a sample code. thanks

Comment: I don't know what type of data you have in your data type so I cannot help you without you posting some code. Thanks

Comment: Thanks I edited the question. I hope to help me with my problem

Comment: You cannot sum up values inside ListView as view are constantly recycled and redrawn. You need to show me the code for your cursor

Comment: is there any way to do this by obtaining the value of the item and then get the result of the sum